# UIAlertController Crash on present

Tags: ios, swift, crash, core-graphics, uialertcontroller

I'm facing a strange crash Using `UIAlertController`.

the crash happens when the `UIAlertController` is presented on the screen.

Here is the error code : `CoreGraphics CGColorSpaceEqualToColorSpaceIgnoringRange`

I made a simpler version of the code which still triggers the crash 100% of the case.

In My Controller

```swift
  @IBAction func handleSaveOrCreate(_ sender: Any) {
    self.showAlert("Test")
  }
```

Here is the code if the showAlert

```swift
  public func showAlert(_ title: String?) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
```

The controller is of the class `AdPeriodViewController`

which is display successfully with this code

```swift
  let vc : AdPeriodViewController = AdPeriodViewController.instance() as! AdPeriodViewController
  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

The IBAction is trigger by the event `TouchUpInside` of a UIButton

I'm compiling in swift 4.2 and running my test on an iPhone 6S+ running iOS 12.2

This crash seems to be only on iOS 12 -> (happen 101 for more than 70 user in the last 7days)

*** Edit for Lame***
[image: ScreenShot of the stask]

In order to limit not by having that shortcut `showAlert` here is what i've done:

```swift
  let alertController =  UIAlertController(title: "title", message: "message", preferredStyle: .alert)
  print(alertController.title) // display Optional("title")
  print(alertController.message) // display Optional("message")
  alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "btnTitle", style: .default, handler: {(alertAction) in print("btnClicked")}))
  self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

More Over is if I change the `preferred style` to `.actionSheet` the crash disappears

Comment: Full error message? Also, could it be because message is nil? Because there is no button? Could you check that?

Comment: It seems that there is a link with CGColor, where do you use this class in your code ?

Comment: You still have not provided (1) code that reliably reproduces the crash for others, or (2) the crash log. Also, your code makes no sense: what is the point of an alert with no button for dismissing it?